# How can I insert new tags around a table in HTML with a particular class using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I know next to nothing about XSLT and have to solve a thorny problem. Our email composition software is producing HTML like this:

```
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F2F2F2"><tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" role="presentation" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed" class="EX_RESPONSIVE_TABLE_768"><tr><td 
class="EX_RESPONSIVE_HIDE_CELL_768" width="138" height="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="EX_RESPONSIVE_HIDE_CELL_768" valign="middle" align="center"><table 
id="ex-table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td 
width="138" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top:5.00px; padding-bottom:5.00px" 
align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; line-height: 1"><span 
style="font-family: 'Arial', serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px; color:#000000">Lorem 
Impsum 1</span></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="HideMSO EX_RESPONSIVE_SHOW_CELL_768" valign="middle" align="center"><table 
id="ex-table2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td 
width="138" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top:5.00px; padding-bottom:5.00px" 
align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; line-height: 1"><span 
style="font-family: 'Arial', serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px; color:#000000">Lorem 
ipsum 2</span></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td></tr></table>
</body>
```

And we need (to support Outlook email clients) to change it to:

```
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F2F2F2"><tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" role="presentation" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed" class="EX_RESPONSIVE_TABLE_768"><tr><td 
class="EX_RESPONSIVE_HIDE_CELL_768" width="138" height="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="EX_RESPONSIVE_HIDE_CELL_768" valign="middle" align="center"><table 
id="ex-table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td 
width="138" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top:5.00px; padding-bottom:5.00px" 
align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; line-height: 1"><span 
style="font-family: 'Arial', serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px; color:#000000">Lorem 
Impsum 1</span></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<!--[if !mso 9]><!--><tr><td class="HideMSO EX_RESPONSIVE_SHOW_CELL_768" valign="middle" align="center"><table 
id="ex-table2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="138" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td 
width="138" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top:5.00px; padding-bottom:5.00px" 
align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><td style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; line-height: 1"><span 
style="font-family: 'Arial', serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px; color:#000000">Lorem 
ipsum 2</span></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr><!--<![endif]-->
</table></td></tr></table>
</body>
```

I'm at a bit of a loss if I'm honest. I've found guides to insert HTML tag + element pairs, but nothing which specifically inserts these tags which wrap around a lump of HTML. I believe from talking to someone that we can use the "hideMSO" class attribute to give XSLT a "hook" to identify the relevant section, but after that I'm lost.

Can anoyne help?

Comment: The usual input to XSLT is XML, not HTML. And you seem to want to insert comments, not tags.

Comment: How is this going to run? Which XSLT engine are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sebastien - I believe it is Xalan, and it's XSLT v1.0. So far I've tried looking at the w3schools xslt lessons and gotten nowhere. Nothing seems comparable to my scenario.

By that I mean looking at the w3schools site, none of the lessons I've seen appear to cover any part of this. There is an insert comment (<xsl:comment>) but I can't see a way to apply this around a table. 

Is there an online tutorial which would get me learning the right stuff? The w3s tutorials seem geared towards very different applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along those lines :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="tr[td[contains(@class,'HideMSO')]]">
    <xsl:comment>[if !mso 9]&gt;&lt;!</xsl:comment> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:comment>&lt;![endif]</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiK/1

Comment: Right, I think I see. the xsl:comment holds the comment contents. 

Can it be changed to wrap the comment tags only around the <tr> containing the table? 

I've found solutions which insert comments, it's the part which wraps it around the <tr> which contains the HideMSO which eludes me.

EDIT: Is it possible to match the td containing HideMSO, then step "up" a level (or two) in xpath, then insert the comment?

Comment: @TomDenyer Yes this should all be possible, but you need to insert more details in your question so that we can get the bigger picture and pinpoint the solution.

Comment: I have updated the question with the whole, ugly HTML file I'm handling at the moment. 

How can I pick up this skill please? IS there a better resource than w3schools or should I start there?